# How to index rows in my output

Tags: python, csv, enumerate

My CSV file is as following (two rows with semicolon separated values)

```
01;John;231;this is row one
02;Paul;745;this is row two
```

I want result like this:

```
01  ============== column 1 and row 1
John ============= Column 2 and row 1
231 ============== column 3 and row 1
this is row one ========column 4 and row 1
```

and so on till the end of csv file.

Till now i am able to fetch column position but not row.

```
def read_csv(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile, 'rb') as file:
        columns = 4
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
        for row in reader:
            for column in range(0, columns):
                 print row[column], ' ====== ', 'column ', column+1, ' and row ',
```

What should i put at the last line of code that i can have row position as well.

Thanks

Comment: Add a variable, say, rownum and add 1 to it after "for row in reader".

Comment: Strictly this wasn't about [tag:csv]. Just a generic question about *How to index rows in my output*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
def read_csv(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile, 'rb') as file:
        columns = 4
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
        # i will count the rows, starting at 1
        for i, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
            for column in range(0, columns):
                 print row[column], ' ====== ', 'column ', column+1, ' and row ', i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` for both and take a slice of each row using iterools.islice, there is no need to use range at all.

```
from itertools import islice  

with open(csvfile) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=";")
    columns = 4
    for ind, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
        for ind2, column in enumerate(islice(row,columns), 1):
            print("{} ======== column {} and row {}".format(column,ind2, ind))


01 ======== column 1 and row 1
John ======== column 2 and row 1
231 ======== column 3 and row 1
this is row one ======== column 4 and row 1
02 ======== column 1 and row 2
Paul ======== column 2 and row 2
745 ======== column 3 and row 2
this is row two ======== column 4 and row 2
```

`range` also starts at 0 by default so you can simply use `range(columns)`, you can also just do regular slicing `enumerate(row[:columns],1)`